# Integrating the world scale ar mapbox project with Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, gps, mapbox, augmented-reality, vuforia

Hello everyone we are trying to make an outdoor augmented reality based navigation application for my university system as our Final Year Project similar to what is shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRmTn25xm7Q) in this video from 7:00 Minutes in. 
Where the path from the user's current location to some building gets augmented using vuforia just like the above video.

We are working with Unity and I found [this sdk and project](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ar-unity) from mapbox which can be really helpful in doing what we want to do.

But the problem is that it only works with ARcore and ARkit.We are developing a system that should work with any android phone android 4.4+ but ARcore at the moment only works with a select 5 or 10 phones.And even when it will get released it will only be for phones with android 7.0+.We are not developing for ios so  ARkit is of no use to us.

We are looking for a way to integrate Vuforia or any other AR framework into the above world scale AR project. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also if anyone of you can provide any alternate way of doing the Augmented reality navigation please guide us in doing so. 
Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution ?